# What is the origin of the division of the Torah into five books

Tags: history, pentateuch-chumash, sefer-torah

As we start Sefer Vayikra, my chavruta and I have again looked for and been unable to find a satisfactory answer to the question:
“What is the origin of the division of the Torah into five books and how ancient is the division - when is it first mentioned in halachic works?”

Answer (score 5):

It’s mentioned in the Gemara [Gittin 60A](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.60a.2?lang=bi) (there may be earlier sources, this is just one I know of):

> שְׁלַחוּ לֵיהּ בְּנֵי גָלִיל לְרַבִּי חֶלְבּוֹ: מַהוּ לִקְרוֹת בְּחוּמָּשִׁים בְּבֵית הַכְּנֶסֶת בְּצִיבּוּר?

> The people of the Galilee sent a question to Rabbi Ḥelbo: What is the halakha with regard to reading from ḥumashim, i.e., scrolls containing only one of the five books of the Torah, in the synagogue in public?

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Gittin.60a.2.1?lang=bi) there explains that it refers to one of the five chumashim, meaning they had this split in the times of the Gemara at least:

> בחומשין - שיש שכותבין להן חמשה חומשין כל חומש אחד שלם לעצמו וכל ספריהם היו במגילה כס"ת שלנו

Edit:

According to the [Midrash Tehillim 1;2](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tehillim.1.2?lang=bi) Dovid Hamelech made Tehillim five books to correspond to the five Chumashim. Furthermore, it indicates that Moshe Rabbeinu himself split it into five

> משה נתן להם חמשה חומשי תורה. וכנגדם נתן להם דוד ספר תהלים שיש בו חמשה ספרים

Comment: The word חומשים literally means "fifths". The singular is חומש a fifth, like the phrase קרן וחומש

Comment: @DoubleAA Does חוּמש have the same meaning as חוֹמש?

Comment: @shmosel חוּמש isn't a word to the best of my knowledge. The plural of חוֹמֶשׁ is חוּמָשִׁים and people who don't know better truncate חוּמָשִׁים to just חוּמָשׁ without realizing the vowel should re-lengthen. (Like the vowels in the familiar stitch לְמקְדְּשֵךְ תּוּב וּלְקוֹדֶשׁ קוּדְשִׁין)